# Visual Studio Debug Mode Typescript files in Script Documents

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript

I can't for the life of me work out why multiple TS files appear associated with my JS file when debugging my website in IE?

Is this normal?

e.g. 
[image: Visual Studio Snip]

Comment: No. Not normal. Perhaps you have multiple tabs open?

Comment: no just the one tab open